# Fill flexible container with centered square component

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

What I try to achieve is shown on following pictures:
[image]

Outer rectangle is a `div` container that can have any size and ratio (it gets resized with browser window resizing), and inside is a component (filled on pictures) that should maintain a 1:1 ratio (square), and should be centered in the container. So its sides are described with the formula `min(container_width, container_height)`.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: The person who down-voted can leave a comment to help me improve the question :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with a combination of three things:

- [**Flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- **[CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)**
- The **[`calc()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)**

Flexbox can be used to ensure that the inner element is both horizontally and vertically centered. This is achieved with only three different rules on the container:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

The key to making the inner element stay square while the parent has a variable width is to base both thew `width` and `height` of the child off of the `height` of the parent.

In the following, I'm basing both the `width` and `height` of the inner square off of the `height` of the parent container (divided by four). Considering the `height` and `width` of the child is defined by the same `--value` as the `height` of the parent, it will always remain square and proportionate:

```css
:root {
  --value: 200px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: var(--value);
}

.box {
  background: black;
  height: calc(var(--value) / 4);
  width: calc(var(--value) / 4);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that this will also work if you base your CSS variable off of the viewport height with the **[`vh` unit](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)**:

```css
:root {
  --value: 50vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: var(--value);
}

.box {
  background: black;
  height: calc(var(--value) / 4);
  width: calc(var(--value) / 4);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: but where is the relation the OP mention at the end**min(container_width, container_height)**

Comment: Thanks @ObsidianAge. Unfortunately I don't have fixed height or width of containing element. For example width and height of container are 50% of window size that gets resized.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Because they're both tied into the same value in my example, the child is always relational to the parent.

Comment: @croraf -- In that case you should just be able to use a percentage-based `width` and `height` on the child, in combination with a `max-width`.

Comment: @croraf - Hmm. So you say you're basing your measurements off of the viewport? You could always set `--value` to be `50vh`; that way the parent would scale with the height of the viewport, and the child would stay square :)

Comment: Well I'm not basing on the viewport directly. The viewport gets resized, and depending on other fixed components and their relations in my hierarchy the container gets resized to some HxV size. In your answer you set container height to fixed 200px, and what if in your answer width gets to 40px, your box will have a width of 50px, so larger than container.

Comment: @croraf - I've updated my answer to show that it works when changing the variable to be based off of the viewport height. Because the child always divides this variable by four with `calc()`, it's always smaller, and always square. View the example full page and resize the page to see this in effect :)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work as expected when viewport is shrinked to less than 50px width.

Comment: You can always divide further if necessary. But if you wish to retain a square, you do unfortunately need to have both the `width` and `height` the same, and these should be based off of the `height` of the parent. Having said that, you shouldn't really be even designing for less than a `400px` wide viewport, so I wouldn't worry about anything less than that :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve your goal with the following code. You will need to set your image as the background of the inner div instead of using a `<img>` directly.

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.inner {
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-300-300-7.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Solution 2: using `<img>` and set the position to absolute.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <img src='http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-300-300-7.jpg'>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like something I try to achieve. But this is only a background image that is centered. The inner div component is still full rectangular width of container. Can you make that a div shrinks as your background image shrinks.

Comment: @croraf you can check the 2nd solution I just added. Hope it helps. :) I don't know why my Chrome stops to shrink around 500px width, but you can open the developer tool and make the browser viewport smaller to see the result.

Comment: It probably stops shrinking because you have many tabs open :). This is better, but unfortunately I need my inner component to be a div instead of image, as it will contain other stuff. I tried using a div instead of image, and setting its height and width but it does not shrink properly :(

Answer (score 1):

If the square is an image in this case you can do something like this  :

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  background:#f2f2f5;
}
img {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width:400px;height:100px;">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
</div>
<div class="container" style="width:200px;height:400px;">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
</div>

<div class="container" style="width:400px;height:400px;">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
</div>
<div class="container" style="width:50px;height:600px;">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
</div>
<div class="container" style="width:600px;height:50px;">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
</div>
```

You need to pay attention when using 100% with height as this will depend on the **parent** of the container and if nothing specified the height will be 0 and thus the image too :

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #f2f2f5;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- this one will not show -->
<div class="container" style="height:100%;">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
</div>


<div style="height:200px">
  <!-- this one will  show -->
  <div class="container" style="height:100%;">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
  </div>
</div>
```

if you want to use a div instead of image you can consider the image inside the div and use `fit-content` value for the width/height and the trick is to make the image not visible and add another div for text content (or anything else).

*Pay attention as **fit-content** is not a standard so not supported by all browser. So you can consider this solution as a pseudo-solution than a generic one*

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #f2f2f5;
}

.content {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}

.content img {
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -999;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width:400px;height:100px;">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
    <div class="text"> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="width:200px;height:400px;">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
    <div class="text"> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="width:400px;height:400px;">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
    <div class="text"> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="width:50px;height:600px;">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
    <div class="text"> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="width:600px;height:50px;">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
    <div class="text"> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: VXp deleted but it seemed OK on first look in FF.  Too bad he deleted, I was going to check what he did. Let me now check yours :).

Comment: @croraf yes but not in Chrome, i think it's not yet supported well with flex implementation

Comment: @croraf i would say he did the same but using flex, i tried it and when i see it was not working i switched to something more supported ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Not the same, your images aren't vertically responsive.

Comment: This looks OK, but I cannot make it work in my application. Can you make an example with just one responsive container that has 100% width, 100% height, so I can resize it in the snippet, and also use div instead of image.

Comment: @croraf pay attention to one detail .. 100% height mean the height of the parent so if there is nothing specified in the parent it will be zero and followin your formula i should take the min(height,width) so the image also will be 0 inside the container ... i will add an example to illsutrate this

Comment: My container has height and width and it gets rendered. I added 100% height and 100%width to your container (instead yours 400px, 200px and 100px) and it has its size. Secondly, I used div instead of img, set its background, and set its width and height, the inner div is not resized accordingly as in your pictures. I also tried to set div's display to inline :D.

Comment: @croraf yes unfortunately it won't work with a div ... the trick is that with image we have predefined height/width so we can keep ratio if we choose square one .. which is not the case with divs. that's why i said in my answer *if the square is an image* :)  but am thinking about a way with div ;)

Comment: @croraf i have an idea, am updating ;)

Comment: @croraf you can check again

Comment: Seems to work OK. It has just a slight problem when both width and height are larger than 400px (that is image size, for example 600 600). I have to set img to have like 2000 2000 size, or even bigger for bigger resolutions.

Comment: @croraf yes but this is not a problem :) you can see this as the limit of the square, so if you put an image 400x400 the square will have this max size and if you want more you add more. I know that you want the relation between parent and child but CSS is a bit limited :s so you can use a big image like you did to avoid this :)

Comment: I'm planning to solve this with javascript. Listen on window resize, then grab the container's width and height, find min of this and set the components dimensions. I will also use flex container with "justify-content: center; and align-items: center;".

Comment: @croraf yes with JS it pretty easy ;) few line of codes ... it's only challenging with CSS :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```css
html, body {width:100%;margin:0}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px; /* needs to be at least the height of the image */
  max-height: 100vh; /* enables vertical responsiveness */
  border: 1px solid Skyblue;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* perfectly centered inside the container */
  display: block; /* removes bottom margin/white-space */
  max-width: 100%; /* horizontal responsiveness */
  max-height: 100vh; /* vertical responsiveness */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300" alt="">
</div>
```